# How can use MySQL locking using a single connection? or any alternative for using a new connection every time am using locks?

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Well I know there is limit to maximum connections MySQL can handle at a time, so my question is

In my application (a discord bot), I've many functions which are using MySQL locks like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and there are quite a chance multiple instances of these functions are executed concurrently so, is MySQL locking possible in a single connection? What I mean here is, is it possible to have a single connection and lock a row and meanwhile another query on that same connection executes updating that same row but this time that query needs to wait till the lock is released.
Currently am using a new connection for each and every query, so I need suggestions what should I do in this case?

Increase `max_connections` ? or Any other way of achieving this?

EDIT:
Currently am using this function each time am executing a query

```py
def execute_query(query,param=None):
 db = connector.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password,database=database)
 db.set_charset_collation('utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_bin')
 cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)      
 try:
  cursor.execute(query,param)   
  reply = cursor.rowcount
  db.commit()
  db.close()
  print("Query executed successfully!")
  return reply  
 except Exception as ex:    
  db.rollback()
  db.close()
  print(ex)
  return ex
```

Comment: Do not use a single connection in a long-running process, use a connection pool that will manage all the connections for you.

Comment: Am not using a single connection, am using a different connection each time am executing a query, I was just asking what should I do? And can you elaborate more about the connection pool you just said.

Comment: Also, one more thing, are locks applied to connections or cursors?

Comment: “What should I do” — I’ve answered it in my comment before, use a single long-term connection pool. What exactly do you want me to elaborate about it?

Comment: "are locks applied to connections or cursors?", in general it would be the cursor that obtains a lock.

Comment: Hmm as far as I understood, connection pooling just saves time of opening and closing connections each time which ultimately increases efficiency but the count of connections remains the same irrespective of whether we use connection pool or open a new connection each time we need to execute a query. Correct me if am wrong.